# Upload file in extjs

Tags: extjs, file-upload

I have to upload a file using browse dialogue. Please help me.. Then what will have to write inside handler()?

```
Ext.create('Ext.ux.tab.Toolbar', {
width: 120,
id:'document-inner-right-tabs',
items: [{                                   
   id:'resumeUpButton',
   tooltip:'Upload',
   disabled:true,
   handler:function(){}                         
}]
});
```

Anyone to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `fileuploadfield` object as described [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File) in the docs. It consists of a field and a button, when clicking the button it will open a file browsing window to allow selection.

If you want, there is also a config to hide the field so it is only a button, you could then save the file location in a variable or something.

Comment: I did use that example but I am still stuck. This is my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571627/adding-csv-upload-browse-button-to-ext-action/12576332#comment17210849_12576332